# Running pipenv scripts on system python

Tags: python, pipenv

Pipenv allows the use of the system Python instead of creating a virtualenv to install packages:

```
$ pipenv install --system
```

But if I do so, subsequent `pipenv run`s are trying to create the virtualenv instead of using the system Python. In particular, I'm interested in using Pipenv scripts:

```
$ pipenv run postinstall
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
```

Is there a way to use the system Python interpreter for Pipenv scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, it's not possible do run the scripts inside the `Pipfile` with `pipenv` if you don't use any

The maintainers of `pipenv` decided against such a feature a couple years ago (e.g. see the discussion at [Add a --system flag to pipenv run #2693](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/pull/2693)), and I can't find anything newer that would say otherwise.

If you want to run a script in your system installation, just run it normally in the terminal. If you work without a virtual environment, you don't need `pipenv` to run any scripts. E.g. if you have defined `app = "uvicorn my_app.main:app --port 8080"` in the `script` section and make a system installation, you can afterwards just call `uvicorn my_app.main:app --port 8080` in the terminal.

I understand that there is some convenience to define some scripts/aliases in the `Pipfile`. But if you need those also outside virtual environments, it would be better to just create actual shell scripts. And if you want to have the `pipenv run` functionality to keep working, just make sure that these scripts defined in the `Pipfile` call the shell scripts in order to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score -1):

When setting up your pipenv you can specify the version of Python by using: `pipenv --python 3.6`, to use Python3.6.

Editing the Pipfile also works, by changing:

```
[requires]
python_version = "3.6.6"
```

to the specific version of Python you want.

If you did all of this and are still having trouble with accessing the correct version of Python from within `pipenv shell` then you might want to check your `.bashrc` file to be sure that you don't have an `alias` for a specific version of Python.

Comment: I'm aware I can specify the Python version and I'm not trying to use `pipenv shell`.